# Unable to update database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-update

I wanted to update a record to the database but it just keep reverting to its original value.
Below is my code. No error was display to me either.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CandidateConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

string updateData = "UPDATE Resume SET [Work_Experience] = @work_exp, [Educational_Level] = @edu_level, [Field_Of_Study] = @field_study, [University_Name] = @uni_name, [University_Location] = @uni_locate, [Graduation_Year] = @gra_year WHERE Cand_ID = (SELECT Cand_ID FROM Candidate WHERE Cand_Username = '"+ usernamelbl.Text +"')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateData, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@work_exp", Work_Exp.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edu_level", Edu_Level.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field_study", Field_Study.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uni_name", Uni_Name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uni_locate", Uni_Locate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gra_year", Year.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Any Problem with the code?

Comment: If you step through the code, are you positive that your code is executing? Also, are you sure you where clause is correct? If you directly execute this SQL against the database (instead of via code) what effect does it have?

Comment: can u put a break point after query and see usernamelbl.text is giving u the value or not . please check tht once

Comment: @mason I'm not sure whether my code is executing or not, but the `WHERE` clause is correct. I just directly execute on the database and the record update perfectly.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code, then step through it line by line. Time to learn to use the debugger! If you're using Visual Studio, directions are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). Learning to step through the code is an invaluable skill that you *must* learn to be a successful programmer.

Comment: Check your update query by directly executing it in sql server.

Comment: @RajeshKannan He already did that. See above comments.

Comment: @ChuahChengJun If you want to know what's happening behind ado.net and sql server while cmd.ExecuteNonQuery then use Sql Server Profiler which you can find it under tools in sql server management studio. Sql server profiler shows the query while the cmd.ExceuteNonQuery excecuted.

Comment: @mason sorry!! juz after your comments I noticed it.

Comment: @mason tried the debugger and usernamelbl.text did give me the value.

Comment: And when you stepped through the code line by line, did you see if `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` was executed or not?

Comment: @RajeshKannan im using VS 2013 to execute the query..

Comment: @ChuahChengJun In Sql Server Management Studio --> Tools --> Sql Server Profiler --> connect --> Run. After doing this, a window opens which displays all the query executed through c# code. So first do the above mentioned steps and then execute the c# code.

Comment: Your code is massively vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). Also, you aren't properly disposing of your connection. You should wrap it in a [using statement](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx).

Comment: @mason Sorry I'm quite new to debugger, how do I identify whether is `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` was executed?

Comment: @ChuahChengJun You step through it line by line. If it goes over that line *and* no exception is raised, then you can be sure the line executed (go watch some YouTube videos about using the VS debugger, because it's absolutely critical that you learn to use it). In which case you should listen to Rajesh who is trying to help you make sure that the SQL statement executed on the database is what you think it is.

Comment: @mason thank you. i just sorted out. its the page_load event problem

Comment: @RajeshKannan thank you too, just sorted it out.

Comment: There you go. You had no idea if/when your code was executing. Using the debugger will help you understand exactly what's going on with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a stupid mistake..

On the page_Load event, I have a line of code which is fetching value from the database

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CandidateConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string getdata = "SELECT * FROM Resume WHERE Cand_ID = (SELECT Cand_ID FROM Candidate WHERE Cand_Username = '" + usernamelbl.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(getdata, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds, "Resume");
                Work_Exp.Text = ds.Tables["Resume"].Rows[0]["Work_Experience"].ToString();
                Edu_Level.Text = ds.Tables["Resume"].Rows[0]["Educational_Level"].ToString();
                Field_Study.Text = ds.Tables["Resume"].Rows[0]["Field_Of_Study"].ToString();
                Uni_Name.Text = ds.Tables["Resume"].Rows[0]["University_Name"].ToString();
                Uni_Locate.Text = ds.Tables["Resume"].Rows[0]["University_Location"].ToString();
                Year.Text = ds.Tables["Resume"].Rows[0]["Graduation_Year"].ToString();
                conn.Close();
```

But I didn't include it under `if(!IsPostBack)` and that's the reason whenever I submit, it overwrites my current value and revert it back to the original state. Thanks to you guys who trying to help me sort out and teaches me about new stuff. :)

Comment: Now that you've got working code, your next step should be to fix the SQL Injection problem and properly wrap it in using statements as I commented above.